# bash : Syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

whatever if statement I try to put into my scripts, I always get the same : syntax error near unexpected token fi'.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
echo $2
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]
then
echo $2
fi
```

I've tried :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
echo $2
if [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]
then
echo $2
fi
```

And:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
echo $2
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
echo $2
fi
```

And many other options, none seem to work.

Comment: Did you by any chance write these scripts on a Windows machine? Also, how do you actually run the scripts from the command line?

Comment: `/bin/sh` isn't always bash, if you use "bashisms" put an explicit `#! /bin/bash`

Comment: I'd recommend you double-quote your variables, too. For example, `[ "$1" -eq 0 ]`

Comment: If I copy your script and put CRLF line endings in it, I am able to cause similar syntax errors, depending on where I put the CRLF.  Run `file` against your script, and see if it says "with CRLF, LF line terminators"

Comment: dos2unix for-the-win

Comment: I'm running the script in a debian command prompt on a Windows machine, and usually call them like this : bash script.sh __ __